# WSO2 soap12 endpoint to soap11 external service

Tags: wso2

I create a simple WSDL proxy in WSO2 to allow Soap 1.2 enabled applications to work with Soap 1.1 only external web service. Everything is fine except WSO2 doesn't transform soap11 replies back to soap12 when I send request via Soap12 WSO endpoint.

```
    <proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="MySOAP" transports="http" 
        statistics="disable" trace="disable" startOnLoad="true">
        <target>
           <endpoint>
           <wsdl service="ExtService" port="ExtPort" uri="https://my.local/wsdl/current
             /ExtService.wsdl"/>
           <property name="DISABLE_CHUNKING" value="true" scope="axis2"/>
           </endpoint>
        </target>
        <publishWSDL uri="file:///home/sysadmin/MySOAP.wsdl"/>
     <description></description>
      </proxy>
```

Has anybody faced anything similar? WSO2 ESB version 4.6.0

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the format as following.

```
    <endpoint>
       <address uri="http://localhost:9000/services/SimpleStockQuoteService" format="soap11" />
   </endpoint>
```

Format - The message format for the endpoint. The available values are:

```
[format="soap11|soap12|pox|get"]
```

- Leave As-Is - No transformation is done to the outgoing message.
- SOAP 1.1 - Transforming message to SOAP 1.1.
- SOAP 1.2 - Transforming message to SOAP 1.2.
- Plain Old XML (POX) - Transforming to plain old XML format
- Representational State Transfer (REST) - Transforming to HTTP Get
  Request
- GET

http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB460/Default+Endpoint

Comment: Shelan, thank you for pointing me out to this. I tried this before. Unfortunately this doesn't work. I'm still receiving SOAP 1.1 responses. I.e proxy doesn't transform them to same format as request was sent in. All I want is simple - I want to exchange with WSO in SOAP12 format, and I want WSO2 exchange with web service in SOAP11 format.

Answer (score 0):

This has been an issue for a while now. See jira https://wso2.org/jira/browse/ESBJAVA-1994.

If you don't want to manually transform your response from the backend, uncomment the relevant NHTTP transport entries in axis2.xml and comment out the HTTP PassThrough transport entries.